# Silverlight LightSwitch - [NoElements] As cadeias dos recursos de depuração não estão disponíveis

Tags: aplicação-web, batch, silverlight

Estou responsável por dar suporte a uma plataforma web feita em Silverlight, na qual não me permitem alterar nada no seu código.
O cliente tem se queixado que por vezes surgem uns erros estranhos mas não faço ideia do que esteja a originar esses erros (nem sempre aparecem).

O erro mais recente foi:

> [NoElements]: As cadeias de recursos de depuração não estão
>   disponíveis. Frequentemente, a chave e os argumentos fornecem
>   informações suficientes para diagnosticar o problema. Consulte
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&version=5.1.50918.00&File=System.core.dll&Key=NoElements

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao abrir o link surge a seguinte mensagem:

> Exception Message
>
> Details The definition of the resource ID could not
>   be found. This webpage provides developers with Silverlight exception
>   message text, which can be useful in diagnosing failures and problems
>   with Silverlight applications. Some exception strings contain tokens
>   for additional information produced by your application.
>
> To see these descriptive error messages on your local machine and
>   obtain other debugging resources, please install the latest version of
>   Silverlight for Developers on your Windows or Mac computer.

Já tentei instalar a última versão do Silverlight no servidor mas o servidor já tem a versão mais recente.
Ainda pensei que seria problema de recursos da máquina mas o servidor tem recursos mais que suficientes.

Analisando os logs do IIS à hora que o user obteve o erro, foi registado um log com os seguintes dados:

```
Método HTTP: POST
HTTP Code: 202
URI Stem: /NomeDaPlataforma/ApplicationData.svc/$batch
```

Pensamos que não seja problema de sessão porque o user tinha feito com sucesso operações 2 minutos antes.

No event viewer não encontramos nada que possa estar relacionado com este erro.

O que poderá ser? Como posso resolver este erro? O que é o `/ApplicationData.svc/$batch`?

Alguém sabe a tradução deste erro em inglês? Já tentei pesquisar em inglês mas não encontro nada sobre este erro.

**Nota:** A minha maior preocupação não é HTTP code 202, é o erro `[NoElements]` que por vezes surge na plataforma.

Comment: Boa tarde.. 2 perguntas... 1) aplicação eh acessada remotamente? 2) só acontece com 1 cliente e tem mais usando sem problemas?

Comment: @itwasme não, a aplicação está publicada num servidor e é acessada normalmente pelo browser como qualquer outro website. Acontece com todo o mundo que acede ao site

Comment: A resposta 202 é intencionalmente não comprometedora. Sua finalidade é permitir que um servidor aceite uma solicitação para algum outro processo (talvez um processo orientado em lote que seja executado apenas uma vez por dia) sem exigir que a conexão do agente do usuário com o servidor persista até que o processo seja concluído. A entidade retornada com essa resposta DEVE incluir uma indicação do status atual da solicitação e um ponteiro para um monitor de status ou uma estimativa de quando o usuário pode esperar que a solicitação seja atendida.

Comment: Dá uma lida aqui https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd315592(v%3dws.10)

Comment: Faça uma coisa, por favor. Troque o navegador que acessa a aplicação. Por exemplo: Se em sua empresa os computadores que acessam o programa usarem windows e o programa for acessado pelo Google Chrome passe a usar o Microsoft Edge e veja se o erro persiste.

Comment: @AugustoVasques como a Microsoft já não dá suporte à tecnologia em que foi criada a aplicação, atualmente só corre no IE.

Comment: @Ninita experimenta esvaziar o cache do IE. Se o cache estiver pressionando pode ser a causa de erros esporádicos e cada vez mais frequentes.

Comment: @Ninita. Como a tecnologia não mais é suportada não é caso de executar o IE como se fosse um [versão anterior do windows](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/975478/guided-help-software-designed-for-an-older-windows-os-cannot-run-on-wi).

Answer (score 5):

Duas informações que você tem que ter em mente. O que é status [HTTP 202](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/202) e a segunda o que é $batch.

**O que é o status HTTP 202?**

Segundo a norma [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.3) o status HTTP 202 significa(tradução livre minha):

O código de status 202 (Aceito) indica que a solicitação foi aceita para processamento, mas o processamento não foi concluído.

A solicitação pode ou não ser eventualmente executada, assim como poderá ser desabilitada enquanto o processo é encaminhado. Não há um dispositivo para reenviar um código de status de um servidor de operação assíncrona.

A resposta 202 é intencionalmente evasiva. Sua finalidade é permitir que um servidor aceite uma solicitação para algum outro processo (talvez um processo orientado por lote que é executado apenas uma vez por dia) sem requerendo que a conexão do agente do usuário ao servidor persista até que o processo seja concluído. O anexo enviado com esta resposta deve descrever o status atual da solicitação e apontar para (ou incorporar) um monitor de status que pode fornecer ao usuário estimativa de quando a solicitação será atendida.

**O que é $batch**

Batch é o arquivo de lotes onde várias informações podem ser elencadas. Uma arquivo batch pode conter:

- informações de configuração
- commandos a serem interpretados
- estruturas de dados
- resultados de operações automatizadas(que é o seu caso).

Servidores normalmente usam `$batch` para proteger informação sensível de ser exposta em URLs ou então usam `$batch` para evitar que as URLs fiquem demasiadamente longas.

**O que ocorreu?**

O status HTTP 202 indica que a operação solicitada pelo usuário foi recebida só que o servidor não tem condições de devolver a resposta informando que a solicitação foi processada ou não, pois a solicitação foi feita de forma assíncrona e referencia entre a origem e o destino foi perdida. Então o servidor gera para o usuário o status HTTP 202 e salva no arquivo `/NomeDaPlataforma/ApplicationData.svc/$batch` o resultado, sucesso ou falha,da operação.

**O que pode gerar esse tipo de situação?**

São inúmeros os fatores que podem gerar esse ruido de comunicação entre o cliente e o servidor. Sem ter acesso ao código fonte da operação não posso dar uma opinião técnica porém posso especular sobre origens externas a ao código fonte, que podem ser:

- virus
- problemas com hardware servidor. Memória, HD e placas de rede devem ser verificados.
- problemas com hardware cliente. Memória e placas de rede devem ser verificados.
- conflito de versão do servidor com o software. O software pode ter sido escrito para uma versão diferente do servidor.
- conflito de versão do Silverlight com o software. O software pode ter sido escrito para uma versão diferente do Silverlight.
- conflito de versão do .NET Framework com o software.O servidor está rodando uma versão diferente do .NET Framework em que o aplicativo foi projetado para rodar.
- algum aplicativo rodando concorrentemente com o software que afete o comportamento do mesmo.
- algum policy ou diretiva que afete o comportamento do aplicativo.

**Como devo proceder?**

Primeira coisa a verificar é o arquivo `/NomeDaPlataforma/ApplicationData.svc/$batch` para saber se as operações estão sendo realizadas ou não. Segunda coisa é procurar por virus ou algum aplicativo que esteja interferindo na operação normal do programa.Ler a documentação do programa e procurar pelo versoramento necessário para as plataformas de operação do programa.Ler a documentação do programa e procurar por policy, diretiva, variáveis de ambiente ou configuração que cause a interferência. Verifique o Hardware em busca de anomalias.
Realizados esse passos preliminares e de posse dos dados do `/NomeDaPlataforma/ApplicationData.svc/$batch` leve esses dados ao programador ou equipe de programação onde será decidido se deverá ser feita uma alteração no código fonte ou então a desativação(não aconselhável) da publicação do status 202 do servidor HTTP.

Comment: O significado do HTTP 202 também eu sei e se não soubesse eu procurava na net. O ficheiro `/NomeDaPlataforma/ApplicationData.svc/$batch` não existe nem nunca existiu, até porque o próprio `ApplicationData.svc` é um ficheiro. Já percebi que realmente ele pode ser importante para eu encontrar o problema mas se ele não existe na pasta da publicação, onde posso encontrá-lo (ou algo semelhante)? No projeto de código não existe nada sobre ele portanto o seu caminho não é configurável. Como já tinha dito, a máquina tem recursos mais que suficiente, e o erro é realmente muito esporádico.

Comment: @Ninita Quem gera o $batch é o servidor você vai ter que procurar nas configurações a pasta em que ele coloca os log e batchs já que `/NomeDaPlataforma/ApplicationData.svc/$batch` é um caminho virtual.

Comment: @Ninita. Como você escreveu que o erro é bastante esporádico, há a possibilidade de  estar ocorrendo em um momento em que o servidor fique sobrecarregado? Pois se o erro estiver ocorrendo em momentos de pico uma possibilidade pode ser que o programa esteja priorizando operações de menor tráfego junto ao servidor e fechando requisições de conexão de requisição que não irá realizar mais nenhuma operação, antes da chegada da notificação de sucesso da operação o que geraria o status 202 no servidor. Se essa for a sequencia de eventos que leva ao problema, só analisando o código fonte para resolver